# GraphQL - The query returned more than one result

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I got the error **The query returned more than one result**

```
type Employee{
    emp_id: Int
    emp_name: String
    manager_id: Int
    job_name: String
}

extend type Query{

# these queries returns the error: "The query returned more than one result."
 Employee(manager_id: Int): Employee @find 
 Employee(manager_id: Int): [Employee] @find

# this query returns all the fields of the DB...
 Employee(manager_id: Int): Employee @all 

}
```

**GraphQL Playground**

```
{
 Employee(manager_id: 66928 ){
   emp_id
   emp_name
   job_name
 }
}


********RESPONSE*******

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The query returned more than one result.",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "graphql"
      },
```

this is my table https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/employee-database-exercise/index.php

Comment: It sounds like your query should return a list (i.e. `[Employee]`) instead since multiple employees can have the same `manager_id`.

Comment: @DanielRearden like this? `Employee(manager_id: Int): [Employee] @find` ... it returns the same error :/

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution

```
type Query {
 Employee(manager_id: Int @where(operator: "=")): [Employee!]! @all 
}
```

It returns what I wanted :D

Comment: This is correct, `@find` won't return multiple: https://lighthouse-php.com/5/api-reference/directives.html#find